# Why does `error.Foo catch {};` compiles, error.Foo is error, not error union

Tags: zig

This code compiles:

```
error.Foo catch {};
```

But not:

```
error.Foo catch |bar| {
    std.debug.print("{s}", .{bar});
};
```

Why is that? Does `catch` without capturing payload works with error too? I thought `catch` only works with error union.

Comment: That sounds like it might be a bug or oversight in zig - the first catch statement does not actually do anything and the code block never runs and there is no mention of that in the documentation.